# Load popup form cross thread

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, thread-safety

I'm having trouble manipulating forms when from another thread.

I've overcome the issue by loading the form at runtime, showing it then hiding it. This means the form is created on the right thread and can be manipulated using invokes.

This is not the right way to do it. I have 3 problems that come from using this method

1. I can't spawn another popup box I have to use the one I created at runtime
2. The forms flash briefly on load - now that I have 3 forms its pretty obvious what I'm doing.
3. I have to use a variable bool to hold if the popup is open or not.

If anyone could point me in the right direction It would be much appreciated. Currently my code looks like:

On Main form Load:

```
        CallerIDfrm = new frmCallerID();
        CallerIDfrm.Show();
        CallerIDfrm.Hide();
```

to manipulate the popup Im using

```
    delegate void StringArgReturningVoidDelegate1(string CallerIDnum, string CallerIDname, string ContactID);
    private void CallerID(string CallerIDnum, string CallerIDname, string ContactID)
    {
        if (CallerIDfrm.InvokeRequired)
        {
            StringArgReturningVoidDelegate1 d = new StringArgReturningVoidDelegate1(CallerID);
            CallerIDfrm.Invoke(d, new object[] { CallerIDnum, CallerIDname, ContactID });
        }
        else
        {

            if (ContactID != null || ContactID != "0")
            {
                CallerIDfrm.ContactID = ContactID;


            }
            CallerIDfrm.Mainfrm = this;
            CallerIDfrm.TopLevel = true;
            CallerIDfrm.TopMost = true;
            CallerIDfrm.lblCallerIDname.Text = CallerIDname;
            CallerIDfrm.lblCallerIDnum.Text = CallerIDnum;
            CallerIDfrm.Show();
            CallerIDOpen = true;

        }
    }
```

To Hide the popup until required again im using:

```
delegate void StringArgReturningVoidDelegate2();

private void CallerIDClose()
{
    if (CallerIDfrm.InvokeRequired)
    {
        StringArgReturningVoidDelegate2 d = new StringArgReturningVoidDelegate2(CallerIDClose);
        CallerIDfrm.Invoke(d, new object[] { });
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            CallerIDfrm.Hide();
            CallerIDOpen = false;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried otherways but the Popup loads as if it is not responding and I loose access to the popup.

Ultimately I'd like to be able to spawn multiple popups and have the ability to close them from the Main Form.

Answer (score 0):

What I gather from your question: You have an caller api/lib/class and you like to show CallerId on a popup form when a call is received. Have a look at [Events and Event Driven programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/).

**The following codes has not been tested, I wrote it from top of my head. Might not compile, they are here to show an example:**

Create an CallReceived event in api/lib class as follows:

```
public event EventHandler<CallReceivedEventArgs> CallReceived;
protected void OnCallReceived(EventArgs e)
{
    var handler = CallReceived;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, e);

    // Note: For C# 6.0 and later, above statements can be simplified to
    // CallReceived?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

*Note: If you don't have access to this api/lib code, create a Gateway class and put your event in there along with mechanism to trigger it.*

Also create a CallReceivedEventArgs, this will be used to *transfer* event data:

```
public class CallReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string CallerIDnum {get; set;}
    public string CallerIDname {get; set;}
    public string ContactID {get; set;}
}
```

Now, in your api/lib class raise this event whenever a call is received:

```
// a call received, replace dummy values with actual values
OnCallReceived(new CallReceivedEventArgs() { CallerIDnum="5554443322", CallerIDname="SOME_NAME", ContactID="SOME_CONTACT" });
```

Finally in your GUI form, register to said event and process accordingly.

```
// inside your main form class
private CallerAPI callerApi = new CallerAPI();

// somewhere inside you main form class, register to event
// from your use case, I would place it inside Main Form's constructor
callerApi.CallReceived += callerApi_Callreceived;

// receive event
void callerApi_Callreceived(object sender, CallReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var callerIDnum = e.CallerIDnum;
    // etc.
    // show callerId form with details
    // you need to change frmCallerID's constructor accordingly
    CallerIDfrm = new frmCallerID(e.CallerIDnum, CallerIDname, ContantID);
    // to be able to track opened popups, you can store them inside a list
    // private List<Form> openPopupList = new List<Form>();
    //
    // alternatively, you can assign CallerIDnum to form's name property
    // and store these inside a List<string> instead of List<Form>
    openPopupList.add(CallerIDfrm);
    CallerIDfrm.Show();
}
```

Don't forget to unregister from event.

```
callerApi.CallReceived -= callerApi_Callreceived;
```

To wrap it up:

> 1. I can't spawn another popup box I have to use the one I created at runtime

You can create and show multiple frmCallerID, independent from each other.

> 2. The forms flash briefly on load - now that I have 3 forms its pretty obvious what I'm doing.

Since new approach creates CallerID forms based on events, you won't see these form flashing. It'll open whenever a CallReceived event is received.

> 3. I have to use a variable bool to hold if the popup is open or not.

A better approach would be: Register to forms FormClosed event, and remove from `openPopupList` accordingly.

```
frmCallerID.FormClosed += frmCallerID_FormClosed;

void frmCallerID_FormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // remove form from openPopupList
    frmCallerID closedPopup = (frmCallerID) sender;
    openPopupList.remove(closedPopup);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to teach me. I will attempt to implement this. And in future am using objects properly. Implementing classes and what not. I am new to C# coming from VB.
Over the course of developing this application I've learnt valuable skills and understand what you are doing in the answer where as I was lost previously.

Once again thank you :)